# `transferOwnership` is not a function

Tags: solidity, hardhat, openzeppelin, inheritance

I am following the challenges from the speedrunEthereum and right now I am stuck on challenge 2 and not getting why the `transferOwnership` is not a function since I am also inheriting the `Ownable` from openzeppelin.

```
pragma solidity 0.8.4;
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/access/Ownable.sol";
import "./YourToken.sol";

contract Vendor is Ownable {
  uint256 public constant tokensPerEth = 100;
  event BuyTokens(address buyer, uint256 amountOfETH, uint256 amountOfTokens);

  YourToken public yourToken;

  constructor(address tokenAddress) {
    yourToken = YourToken(tokenAddress);
  }

  function buyTokens() public payable {
    uint256 tokensAmount = tokensPerEth * msg.value;
    yourToken.transfer(msg.sender,tokensAmount);
    emit BuyTokens(msg.sender,msg.value,tokensAmount);
  }

}
```

deployment script:

```
// deploy/01_deploy_vendor.js

const { ethers } = require("hardhat");

module.exports = async ({ getNamedAccounts, deployments }) => {
  const { deploy } = deployments;
  const { deployer } = await getNamedAccounts();
  const chainId = await getChainId();

  // You might need the previously deployed yourToken:
  const yourToken = await ethers.getContract("YourToken", deployer);

  // Todo: deploy the vendor
  const vendor = await deploy("Vendor", {
    from: deployer,
    args: [yourToken.address], 
    log: true,
  });
  // Todo: transfer the tokens to the vendor
  console.log("\n   Sending all 1000 tokens to the vendor...\n");
  
  const transferTransaction = await yourToken.transfer(
    vendor.address,
    ethers.utils.parseEther("1000")
  );

  console.log("\n    ✅ confirming...\n");
  await sleep(5000); // wait 5 seconds for transaction to propagate
  await transferTransaction.wait();

  // ToDo: change address to your frontend address vvvv
  console.log("\n   Sending ownership to frontend address...\n")
  const ownershipTransaction = await vendor.transferOwnership("0x64b2a2caf782c54998F5d0667AE71D7bF898Bc5F");
  console.log("\n    ✅ confirming...\n");
  const ownershipResult = await ownershipTransaction.wait();

};
```

I am not getting why the `transferOwnership` is not a function. Since it's public also in openzeppelin.

Comment: any answer to this?